# datalist items need to float

Tags: css, datalist

I have the following code which is created with a datalist control:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmE2E/1/

But i am unable to float the to ULs side by side with padding in between.
Please can you help?

edit: added code

```
<span style="display:inline-block;background-color:Transparent;border-color:#404040;border-style:None;" id="DataList1"><span style="color:Transparent;background-color:Transparent;">

                <ul class="latest-posts">
                   <li>
                    <a href="http://www.site.co.uk/blog/post/using-jquery.aspx">
                        using jquery<br>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </span><br><span style="color:Transparent;background-color:Transparent;">

                <ul class="latest-posts">
                   <li>
                       <a href="http://www.test.co.uk/First-Blog-Post.aspx">
                        First Blog Post<br>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </span></span>
```

**css**

```
ul.latest-posts
{
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid black;
}


ul li.latest-posts

{
    float:left;            
}
```

Comment: Please include the code in your post as well.

Comment: i have included a jsfiddle which had the code

Comment: Yes, but a question should be self-contained and understandable without having to follow a link. The demo is a great and useful supplement but what if the link breaks or jsfiddle is (temporarily) down? So please add your code.

Comment: understood, i have added some code. sorry

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see fiddle for code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vmE2E/2/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vmE2E/2/embedded/result/

Comment: bhai could you look at this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991377/displaying-a-hidden-div-with-a-scroll-down-effect-using-jquery-on-hover

Answer (score 1):

That is some unusual/unnecessary use of markup (inline block `span`, `span` used as containers for block elements, etc). Simply removing that `<br>` will put your sections next to one another (but not because they float but because they are `span`, meaning they stay inline)